# Where Can I Discuss Math Rather Than Only Ask About It?

Tags: discussion

On Math Stack Exchange, I can only ask questions. Is there a place to discuss mathematics without necessarily asking a question?

Comment: Our chatrooms and [XKCD math forum](http://fora.xkcd.com/viewforum.php?f=17) come to mind. There are many others, but those are the ones that came to my mind right away. ... And I'm sure some take that view that this question is A) duplicate and B) off-topic because it is not about Math.SE :-)

Comment: Related: [Can the chat be used to discuss opinionated questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22856/can-the-chat-be-used-to-discuss-opinionated-questions)

Comment: Could you please change the title of your question to something more descriptive. The title *My First Question Here on Meta* definitely does not describe what the question is about at all.

Comment: Sometimes I have things to tell other mathematicians about.

Comment: Start a blog. You can do whatever you want there.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6863/discussing-ideas-on-math-se).